# Connecting Anroid app with PI3 and touchscreen

Tags: pi-3, touchscreen, android

Can a touchscreen be used with RPI3 to open Andorinha apps?

Comment: What is Andorinha? A soccer club?

Comment: @DmitryGrigoryev: When I googled it, a [swallow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Swallow) came up.

Answer (score 0):

A touchscreen is just a generic IO device. Assuming you have an appropriate driver for it to interface with your operating system, it can of course be used to launch and control applications.

That being said, I see that you've used [android](/questions/tagged/android). At the time of this writing, I have still yet to see any usable distribution of Android on the RPi. Even if you manage to find one that works well enough for your needs, it's unlikely you'll find a touchscreen that then supports Android.